# Converting a CSV file to ARFF with weka.jar

Tags: java, weka

For my project, I am using weka.jar. I am converting a CSV file to ARFF using following code:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

import java.io.File;

public class CsvArffConverter
{

 public static void Convert(String sourcepath,String destpath) throws Exception
 {
 // load CSV
 CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
 loader.setSource(new File(sourcepath));
 Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

 // save ARFF
 ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
 saver.setInstances(data);
 saver.setFile(new File(destpath));
 saver.setDestination(new File(destpath));
 saver.writeBatch();
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {
 Convert("C:\\ad\\BSEIT.csv", "C:\\ad\\test.arff");

 }
}
```

However, on executing, I am getting following error:

```
Cannot create a new output file. Standard out is used.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot create a new output file (Reason: java.io.IOException: File already exists.). Standard out is used.
    at `enter code here`weka.core.converters.AbstractFileSaver.setDestination(AbstractFileSaver.java:421)
    at Predictor.CsvArffConverter.Convert(CsvArffConverter.java:29)
    at Predictor.CsvArffConverter.main(CsvArffConverter.java:34)
```

Comment: Solution: With versions of Weka later than 3.5.3 the call of saver.setDestination(new File(args[1])); is no longer necessary, it is automatically done in the saver.setFile(new File(args[1])); method.

Comment: I have the same exact problem while saving a dataset file in ".arff" format, overwriting the old one. Sometimes it works like a charm, sometimes it throws that same exception. Without changing anything, simply re-running my code. Same exact conditions. Could it be due to Windows 7 blocking the file sometimes, thus not allowing the deletion?

Comment: By the way, I'm using    "ConverterUtils.DataSink.write(destinationFilePath, datasetObject);",    which is an upper level construction that lets the Weka classes manage the underlying details.

Comment: I have the same problem but this solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [weka mail list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2011-January/050901.html), this error is a file issue, may be permission. Other emails suggest to use [Java I/O approch](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Save+Instances+to+an+ARFF+File) to save arff file.

> ```
> This error is coming from the CSVSaver and indicates that it is unable 
> to create the directory and/or file that you've specified. More than 
> likely it is something to do with permissions on where it is trying to 
> write to.
> ```

Try following code.

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

import java.io.File;

public class CsvArffConverter
{
    public static void Convert(String sourcepath,String destpath) throws Exception
    {
        // load CSV
        CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
        loader.setSource(new File(sourcepath));
        Instances dataSet = loader.getDataSet();

        // save ARFF
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destpath));
        writer.write(dataSet.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close(); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Convert("BSEIT.csv", "test.arff");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use relative paths. Since absolute path writing may be blocked due to permission issues.